# Activate a sheet name from a variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm working on a medium-sized spreadsheet. It is to mitigate the amount of copy/paste I do for portfolio management.

I'm simulating deficits over a number of years so I have many sheets whose name is the year of interest (ex: 2025). My goal is to iterate over all year sheets (there are 65) and paste values that I've saved into an array from other sheets. It's a sort of 'yearly portfolio summary'.

When I try to reference the sheets dynamically using a variable created from my loop index, the script fails with

> runtime error 9

I tried converting the indexed value into a string.

I placed the explicitly typed year number into the `sheets().activate` method (ex: Sheets("2025").Activate) and it worked.

The debugger shows all variables possessing expected values.

I tried passing the variable as an integer, string, concatenated string, and strongly typed. The only attempt which resulted in the sheet activating was the case where I strongly typed the sheet name.

I expect the dynamic value of the sheet name to pass to the activate method and it activate the sheet name represented by the variable.

```vb
Sub create_yearly_sheets()
    Dim current_year_string As String
    Sheets("supplemental needs").Activate
    from_year = Range("C2").Value
    to_year = Range("C3").Value
    
    Dim copying_array(0 To 100) As Variant
    
    Dim city_array(0 To 50) As String
    
    ' get all of the city name for sheet selection
    Sheets("unit allocations").Activate
    For i = 2 To 100 Step 1
        If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
            city_array(i - 2) = Range("A" & i).Value
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    For k = from_year To to_year Step 1
        current_year = k
        For i = 0 To UBound(city_array) Step 1
            If city_array(i) <> "" Then
                Sheets(city_array(i)).Activate
                For j = 1 To 50 Step 1
                    If Cells(5, j).Value = current_year Then
                        current_year_column = j
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                
                For h = 6 To 100 Step 1
                    If Cells(h, current_year_column) <> "" Then
                        copying_array(q) = Cells(h, current_year_column).Value
                        q = q + 1
                    End If
                Next h
                
                ' go to the year sheet and past it down
                current_year_string = Str(current_year)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(current_year_string).Activate
                i_last_empty_cell = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' find the last cell with date in it and use as iterator
                For p = 2 To UBound(copy_array) + 2 Step 1
                    If copy_array(p - 2) <> "" Then
                        Cells(i_last_empty_cell, p).Value = copy_array(p - 2)
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next p
            End If
        Next i
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: my bad. should probably remove my other attempts to understand the problem. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(current_year_string).Activate      casts the error

Comment: Just tried it. script still casts the same error. "Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range". `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(current_year)).Activate` doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: Do you have a sheet named that matches `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(current_year)).Activate`

Comment: yes. sheets "2025" exists. code snippet `Sheets("2025").Activate` works. the variable is `2025` before string conversion. `"2025"` after string conversion. another posters mentioned there's a white space for left during the conversion. maybe that?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this. For example, the subroutine `Sub tester()`, `Dim x As Long`, `x = 2025`, `Debug.Print Sheets(Cstr(x)).Name`, `End Sub`. So likely `current_year` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `current_year_string = Str(current_year)` should be `current_year_string = CStr(current_year)`. `CStr` and `Str` are not equivalent!

Comment: `Sub checking_sheet_references()` `For i = 2025 to 2028 step 1` `Sheets(CStr(i)).Activate` `Next i` `End Sub` This doesn't work. Is there a way I can pass the index as sheet name?

Comment: You really need to specify the parent workbook before `Sheets`.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Data

- The name of the procedure doesn't fit what your code is doing. The whole thing doesn't make much sense. I played around a bit and this is what I got.
- The results are the columns in the two yearly sheets. There are still many issues remaining with this code.

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateYearlySheets() ' ???
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Get the start and end years and the year step.
    
    Dim Startyear As Long, EndYear As Long
    
    With wb.Sheets("Supplemental Needs")
        Startyear = .Range("C2").Value
        EndYear = .Range("C3").Value
    End With
    
    Dim YearStep As Long: YearStep = IIf(Startyear <= EndYear, 1, -1)
    
    ' Return all (unique) cities in a dictionary.
    
    Dim Cities As Object: Set Cities = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Cities.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' enforce case-insensitivity ('A=a')
    
    Dim CityData(), r As Long, CityString As String
    
    With wb.Sheets("Unit Allocations")
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            CityData = .Value ' assumes at least 2 rows
            For r = 1 To UBound(CityData, 1)
                CityString = CityData(r, 1)
                If Len(CityString) > 0 Then
                    If Not Cities.Exists(CityString) Then
                        Cities(CityString) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            Next r
        End With
    End With
    
    Dim cell As Range, YData(), City, yc, y As Long, yRows As Long
    
    For y = Startyear To EndYear Step YearStep
        For Each City In Cities.Keys
            With wb.Sheets(City)
                ' Attempt to store the year column in a variable ('yc').
                With .Range("A5", .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                    yc = Application.Match(y, .Cells, 0)
                End With
                If IsNumeric(yc) Then ' year column found
                    ' Return the non-empty values in the years array ('YData').
                    With .Range(.Cells(6, yc), .Cells(.Rows.Count, yc).End(xlUp))
                        ReDim YData(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
                        For Each cell In .Cells
                            If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) > 0 Then
                                yRows = yRows + 1
                                YData(yRows, 1) = cell.Value
                            End If
                        Next cell
                    End With
                End If
                If yRows > 0 Then
                    ' Copy the top values from the array to the years sheet.
                    With wb.Sheets(CStr(y))
                        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                            .Resize(yRows).Value = YData
                        End With
                    End With
                    yRows = 0
                End If
            End With
        Next City
    Next y
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```